# Business-To-Buyer API Endpoints For Major E-Commerce Sellers

Tags: e-commerce, portal, b2b, amazonsellercentral, serpapi

**What are the details of your problem?**

Please excuse my ignorance, are there REST or GraphQL endpoints for consumer buyers from big retail companies?

I have a friend that's gotten himself into Disney Lorcana and now he wants to automate purchasing their cards.
Not looking to enable him, but this is a great excuse to have a direction-goal on finally learning [B2B (Business-to-Business) APIs](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api). I'm not looking create a seller-account with billing information and he the same with me. Plus, all the major retailers seem to only provide seller developer-portals and some with [monthly subscription fees of $39.99 USD](https://sell.amazon.com/pricing) just to have access to use. I just want to show my friend a way to automate buying a booster pack to maybe delivered every Friday for him.

**What did you try and what were you expecting?**

I tried internet searching for such information. Which lead me cross information like: developer portals that need seller signups, seller account setups with personal information, and seeming web-scraper that are meant to repackage business endpoints which I have no way to verify if they're trustable or accurate.

1. Developer Portals include: [Amazon](https://developer.amazonservices.com/), [Target](https://developer.target.com/), [Walmart](https://developer.walmart.com/), [Home Depot](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeDepot/comments/8l1tkw/home_depot_public_apis/) (looking to reuse this knowledge for another friend), and [Best Buy](https://developer.bestbuy.com/apis)
2. Seller Signup Sites include: [Amazon](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/), [Target Plus](https://plus.target.com/), [Walmart](https://seller.walmart.com/), [Best Buy Partners](https://partners.bestbuy.com/canada/marketplace)
3. Unverified 3rd-Party API-Providers include: [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/), [BigBox API](https://www.bigboxapi.com/), and [others](https://medium.com/@hartator/serpapi-vs-zenserp-vs-serpstack-vs-serpwow-vs-scaleserp-benchmarks-6ef5fd467f7d)